# System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory when having a @ in a ODBCCommand

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc

I am running into an interesting problem for which I can't find a solution yet.

We are running the following code against a MySQL database.
The goal of the code is to populate a column with a rownumber.
The SQL code itself runs fine when executed through HeidiSQL but causes an System.AccessViolationException when being executed from our C# code.

code:

```
string fill_rowcounter_query = "SET @pos = 0; UPDATE tableA SET rowcounter = ( SELECT @pos := @pos + 1 );";
OdbcCommand fill_rowcounter_cmd = new OdbcCommand(fill_rowcounter_query, MariaDBConn);

MariaDBConn.Open();
fill_rowcounter_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MariaDBConn.Close();
```

I'm 100% sure the crash occurs because of the @pos which probably is marked as a parameter by the OdbcCommand. If I remove the @ the System.AccessViolationException no longer happens but of course the wanted result of having the column populated by rownumbers isn't happening.

I tried all kinds of things like supplying the @pos as a parameter to the OdbcCommand and by adding a @ to the fill_rowcounter_query string to indicate it as a literal string but both options do not give the wanted result.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Apparently the issue is not in the @ but instead it occurs because of the semicolon.

If I change the query to

```
string fill_rowcounter_query = "SELECT 1; UPDATE TableA SET rowcounter = 1;";
```

I still get the same error. Removing the SELECT 1; part makes the query run without errors leading me to believe the issue is with the semicolon.

Comment: I think the issue is the ODBC driver.  Are yo using the same connection string in MariaDBConn and HeidiSQL?  The CommandText (fill_rowcounter_query) syntax would be exactly the same as  HeidiSQL.

Comment: Hi @jdweng yes both the connection strings are identical.

Comment: ODBC is a standard the describes the input and outputs to a database driver.  The Net library is an interface that passes the c# instructions to the driver.   So you have three pieces 1) Connection String 2) Command Text (the string query) 3) Parameters.  So what works in one application should also work in a different application.  There are some differences.  For example one database may use dollar signs in the command text and parameters for variables and another may use a '@' for parameters.  So what works in HeidiSQL should also work in c#.